# Why does black glass reflect better than white one?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

Why does black glass reflect better than white glass? Both of them are glasses, so they reflect light. But why black glass reflects better?

See below, shiny black glass.

[image]

Comment: Understand that the reflection is not from the body of the glass (where the color is), but from the surface.  The amount of light reflected is only a few percent.  The dark glass below the surface absorbs light that isn't reflected (and prevents light from being transmitted through from the other side) so that contrast is improved (as Carl suggests).

Comment: Simply wrong! If You place a black paper behind a colorless glass, you will see that there is no difference. Refection by transparent media is a funktion of angle and refractive index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confusing reflectivity with contrast or other effects.  When we look at a reflection from a shiny black surface, our eye/brain adjusts for the image darkness and retains the colors.  Reflection from a white surface gets (I think, not absolutely sure here) overloaded with the underlying diffuse signal and it's harder to discriminate.

Comment: Ah, because most of the light gets reflected from **white glass**, a lot of stray light gets reflected. This causes reflected image to be less clear?

Comment: @ThePragmatick I think so -- whiteness tends to be perceived, as opposed to the "shiny grey" of a mirror, due to a certain percentage of scatter.

Comment: related http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_mirror

Answer (score -2):

Glasses primarily transmit light, but part is also reflected, so that they are characterised by a number, reflectivity (or reflectance), while the transmittance is related to it by complementarity (the total intensity must be conserved, although part of the light might even be absorbed or interfere with itself and cancel out). Dark glasses are usually treated with coating (like an anti-reflex coating) that change the value of the reflectivity

Comment: Anti-reflex coating (AR) as well increases transmission. Instead of dark, it will be brighter indeed, by avoiding [Fresnel equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations). E.g. for BK7 glass slab the transmission may be increased from 92% (4% reflectivity at each interface fo n=1.5) to 99%.